Questions about continuity and differentiability of a function
I have a problem trying to check if a function is continuous and differentiable. I know that
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{\sin(y)}{x}, & x \neq 0, \\
                 0 & x = 0.\end{cases}$$
I know that the function is continuous, because is compounded by two continuous functions, but I need to check the limit in $(0,0)$, right? My question is: If I demonstrate that in some curves ($x=0$, $y=0$, etc.) the limit is the same, can I say that the function is continuous?
And can I ask something more? Assuming that the function is continuous by the previous step, I need to check the partial derivatives of $f(x,y)$ by definition, right? This will allow me to prove that it is differentiable.
Thanks!

What does $sen$ stand for?

I suspect it's the sine function. It's abbreviated that way in Spanish and Italian (and Latin...)

I don't think the function is continuous.

The limit has to be the same for every curve. Let $y=mx$. $\sin(mx)/x \to  m$. So approaching from lines of different slopes yields a different limit. Further, these limits differ from $0$.

A function is continuous at $c$ if for any path passing through $c$, the function along the restriction has the same limit.
So showing limits along two paths only tell you that it may be continuous at $(0,0)$, but not telling you it must be continuous.
More likely, you can try $y=x$ and $y=0$.
And for a multivariable function to be differentiable, the existence of partial derivative is not sufficient (you can regard the partial derivatives of the function, is only the derivative of the function restricting to the path $x=0$ and $y=0$ respectively, a very very weak condition for just the existence of partial derivative). More likely, you need to show that the partial derivatives are continuous.
On the other hand, you can also prove the function is differentiable by definition, i.e. showing as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ $$\dfrac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-Df(0,0)}{\|(x,y)-(0,0)\|}\to0$$
As a remark, continuous and the existence of partial derivatives are two not related concepts, but if a function is not continuous, then it must not be differentiable.
